# Can we use v-for in a custom component's template in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js

use following code in html, it works:

```
<div v-for="i in [1,2,3]" >{{i}}</div>
```

but when used in a component template:

```
Vue.component('test', {    
    template: '<div v-for="i in [1,2,3]" >{{i}}</div>'
})
```

It will trigger an error:

```
- Cannot use v-for on stateful component root element because it renders  multiple elements.
```

any idea putting a v-for in this situation? Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because doing that, the result of `test` component will become

```
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
```

A component must have a root element. Adding a root `<div>` then it should work:

```
Vue.component('test', {    
    template: '<div><div v-for="i in [1,2,3]" >{{i}}</div></div>'
})
```

output:

```
<div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```